# External data objects - SharepointOnline SharePoint: System.NotSupportedException

Tags: lightning-connect

We activated the new functionality in Salesforce to allow users to search in an external system using the sunlight search functionality (External data sources)

We configured everything for Sharepoint online. Connection seems to work fine but the functionality does not work with sharepoint online 2013.

If we search we get this error:
We encountered this error while searching SharepointSite: SharePoint is unable to perform the query. Message from SharePoint: System.NotSupportedException

Configuration in salesforce should be ok
[image]

I added result scopes in the repository field (result scopes are the replacement of search scopes which is deprecated in 2013)

Did anybody got this working or has an idea on how to go forward now?

thx

Sven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed since the latest release, so this question is not relevant anymore